# Compare two numbers in a QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

There are two values:

```
QString str1 = "3.5.8", str2 = "20.3.6";
```

Let's imagine that these two `numbers` represent the software `version`, as it were.

It is known that `QString` compares character-by-character.

What if we approach this decision in this way:

```
str1.replace(".","");
str2.replace(".","");
int n = str1.toInt();
int m = str2.toInt();

if (n >= m)
{
    qDebug() << "YES";
} else if (n <= m) {
    qDebug() << "NO";
}
```

Maybe there is a more optimal and correct way to do this.

Could you tell me please how I can translate these values into numbers so that they can be compared in their entirety. Thanks.

Comment: Should version "3.5" compare greater or less than version "2.1567"? I'd think you'd want to compare major version, then if they're equal compare minor version, then if they're equal compare revision. Just getting rid of the separators and comparing them as integers won't do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `QVersionNumber` class was designed to solve this problem (requires Qt 5.6+):

```
QVersionNumber version1 = QVersionNumber::fromString(str1);
QVersionNumber version2 = QVersionNumber::fromString(str2);

if (version1 > version2)
{
    qDebug() << "YES";
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "NO";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Quite frankly I'd first parse them to real ints, and then convert those; something like this:

```
const std::string s1  = str1.toStdString();
const std::string s2  = str2.toStdString();
struct { int major, minor, tag; } v0, v1;
int r1=sscanf(s1.c_str(),"%i.%i.%i",&v0.major,&v0.minor,&v0.tag);
...
```

Then you can compare versions on major/minor/etc as you require. Of course you do want to add some error-checking on the result of sscanf, and possibly look into sscanf_s for safety concerns.

Answer (score 3):

Use `split` method to have `QStringList`s, use `std::transform` to convert them to `vector<int>`, finally use `lexicographical_compare`.

Suboptimal performance-wise, verbose, but correct and idiomatic.